# jquery toggle state

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to swaps text to original text in a button by using twiter-bootstrap.

Here is the documentation:

```
$().button('reset'); 
// Resets button state - swaps text to original text.

$().button(string)
// Resets button state - swaps text to any data defined text state.
```

Reference: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons

Here is my code (1) and here is my demo on jsfidlle http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2646/

As you can see when I try to click on the button it changes text as expected.
Then when I try to click again it does not change text.
How should I fix my code?

---

(1)

```
var buttonElement = $(document.createElement('button'));

buttonElement.text('hide');
buttonElement.attr('data-complete-text', 'show');

buttonElement.on('click', function (event) {
    $('.alert').toggle(function () {
            buttonElement.button('complete');
            // buttonElement.button('reset');
        }
    );
});

$('body').append(buttonElement);
​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, but I'm not sure if there's a better way to accomplish this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Shmiddty/D2RLR/2651/

```
var buttonElement = $(document.createElement('button'));

buttonElement.text('hide');
buttonElement.attr('data-complete-text', 'show');
buttonElement.attr('data-default-text', 'hide');
buttonElement.on('click', function(event) {
    $('.alert').toggle(function() {
        buttonElement.button($(this).is(':visible') ? 'default' : 'complete');
    });
});

$('body').append(buttonElement);​
```

Ah, there is a better way: http://jsfiddle.net/Shmiddty/D2RLR/2655/

```
var buttonElement = $(document.createElement('button'));

buttonElement.text('hide');
buttonElement.attr('data-complete-text', 'show');
buttonElement.on('click', function(event) {
    $('.alert').toggle(function() {
        buttonElement.button($(this).is(':visible') ? 'reset' : 'complete');
    });
});

$('body').append(buttonElement);​
```

​

Comment: I would also recommend using `slideToggle` as opposed to `toggle`. It will make it slide up instead of up and to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following js code:

```
var buttonElement = $(document.createElement('button'));

buttonElement.text('hide');

buttonElement.on('click', function (event) {
    $('.alert').toggle(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
            buttonElement.text('show');
        } else {
            buttonElement.text('hide');
        }
    });
});

$('body').append(buttonElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code sample above.  Keep in mind toggle takes multiple functions that it will "toggle" through.

```
var buttonElement = $(document.createElement('button'));

buttonElement.text('hide');
buttonElement.attr('data-complete-text', 'show');

buttonElement.on('click', function (event) {
    $('.alert').toggle(function () {
            buttonElement.button('complete');
        },
        function() {
           buttonElement.button('reset');
        }
    );
});

$('body').append(buttonElement);
​
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but it does not work: here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2647/